# Is there a way to sort and combine values from multiple columns into a single column using R?

Tags: r

Is there a way to sort and combine values from multiple columns into a single column using R?

For example: if I have a Data Frame as below:

```
     [1]  [2] [3]
[1]   2   bb  cat
[2]   3   cc  bat
[3]   5   xx  sat
```

I want to write code that creates a new column that sort the first 3 values and then combines them into a comma separated value

Expected Output:

```
     [1]  [2] [3]  [4]
[1]   2   bb  cat  2,bb,cat
[2]   3   cc  bat  3,bat,cc
[3]   5   xx  sat  5,sat,xx
```

Comment: The data frame you entered looks more like a vector. It's very difficult to see how this is structured.  Can you insert the `dput` of your data.frame?  For example, `dput(YOUR_DATA_FRAME_NAME)`

Comment: I have formatted the question better now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
m<-(transpose(data.frame(apply(df, 1, sort)))) ## Sort the dataframe, transpose it back to normal
m<-data.frame(d=m$V1, a=m$V2, t=m$V3) #Rename the columns
cols <- c('d','a','t')  #select the columns you want to paste together
m$x <- do.call(paste, c(m[cols], sep=",")) #create the new column with pasted columns

m

d   a   t        x
1 2  bb cat 2,bb,cat
2 3 bat  cc 3,bat,cc
3 5 sat  xx 5,sat,xx
```

Comment: Your dataframe columns were previously 'd','a' and 't'. You have changed your Q now

Comment: Below are my commands:

d = c(2, 3, 5) 
a = c("bb", "cc", "xx") 
t = c("cat","bat","sat") 
df = data.frame(d, a, t) 

m<-(t(data.frame(apply(df, 1, sort)))) ## Sort the dataframe, transpose it back to normal
m <- as.data.frame(m)
colnames(m) <- c("d","a","t")
cols <- c('d','a','t')  #select the columns you want to paste together
m[cols]
m$x <- do.call(paste, c(m[cols], sep=",")) #create the new column with pasted columns
df <- cbind(df,m$x):